# Django POST data to via form and redirect to page with POST data

Tags: django

I have a Django form, that once the data has been submitted I'd like to redirect to another page where the data will be displayed.

I'm having trouble as I don't know how to retrieve the Foreign Key until the form has been submitted

Form

```
class addEventForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(addEventForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    class Meta:
        model = Event
        fields = '__all__'
```

View

```
class addEventView(LoginRequiredMixin,View):
    template_name = 'pages/add_event.html'

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return render(request, self.template_name)

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        form = addEventForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            data = {"success": "successfully added"}
        else:
            data = {"error": form.errors}
        return JsonResponse(data, safe=False)
```

JS

```
onst xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open("POST", "/pages/add_event");
        xhr.setRequestHeader("X-CSRFToken", csrftoken);
        xhr.send(formdata);
        xhr.onload = () => {
            window.location.reload();
        };
```

How do I redirect but pull in the data from the `POST`?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of [CreateView](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/class-based-views/generic-editing/#createview) and `success_url`

Give this a try

```
from django.views.generic.edit import CreateView
from django.urls.base import reverse_lazy

class addEventView(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    template_name = 'pages/add_event.html'
    model = Event
    form_class = addEventForm
    success_url = reverse_lazy('url_name_you_want_to_redirect_to')
```

FYI: *in python, Class names should normally use the CapWords convention, so better change `addEventForm` to `AddEventForm` and `addEventView` to `AddEventView` respectievely.*

Comment: Thanks Sumithran, I can't get this to work, but this maybe down to the way i am posting the data. As i am using JavaScript to POST.

Comment: Just add a print statement in your post method and see if it is receiving the correct data..

Comment: When I replace my view with what's suggested, my page breaks. I am probably doing something wrong as I've only just started working with Django. I have added my JS post as I think this is the issue and as maybe i need to use ModelForms for this instead?

Comment: BTW are you getting any errors?